# Refresh TabActivity when back button is pressed

Tags: android, maps, tabactivity

I have the following code that onCreate populates a webview with a Google map. In my case when the tab is first clicked my phone asks me if I want to use the internet or the Google maps app. That’s fine but when I go to a map and hit the back button the map no longer loads if I click the map tab again, without onResume.

With onResume in the code, I cant go back at all, I get stuck in an endless loop, that continually pops up the dialog that asks me if I want to use the internet or Google maps!

Does anyone know of a way around this? Can I flag it somehow, the other option is to not use Tabs but tabs are preferred.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);

    Intent browseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com.au/maps?q=Cape+Schanck,+Victoria&hl=en&sll=-25.335448,135.745076&sspn=62.858164,114.169922&vpsrc=0&hnear=Cape+Schanck+Victoria&t=h&z=13&source=gplus-ogsb"));
    startActivity(browseIntent);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent browseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com.au/maps?q=Cape+Schanck,+Victoria&hl=en&sll=-25.335448,135.745076&sspn=62.858164,114.169922&vpsrc=0&hnear=Cape+Schanck+Victoria&t=h&z=13&source=gplus-ogsb"));
    startActivity(browseIntent);
}
```

Cheers,

Mike.

Comment: Don't put identical code in both `onCreate()` and `onResume()`. `onResume()` is ALWAYS called sometime after `onCreate()` so basically you can cause an avalanche effect (probably what you're seeing). Use `onCreate()` to do one-off initialization of an `Activity` and put any other generic code in `onResume()`.

Comment: Thanks MisterSuuonk. I’ve removed the Intent from the onCreate method but I get the same avalanche result. Is there a way this can be done with intent, I guess I’m trying everything I can to not have to use a MD5 code and register my maps, it is not the way forward for this app.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve gotten around my problem by putting the following code in the map tab/activity.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.loadmap);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent browseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com.au/maps?q=Cape+Schanck,+Victoria&hl=en&sll=-25.335448,135.745076&sspn=62.858164,114.169922&vpsrc=0&hnear=Cape+Schanck+Victoria&t=h&z=13&source=gplus-ogsb"));
            startActivity(browseIntent);    
        }
    });
}
```

It is one extra screen tap to get to the map but as the whole idea behind this app is you can get most of the information while in flight mode, the button also warns the user that they will have to go online to to view the map.

It’s a work around, but that programming.

If someone has a better way of doing this please let me know.

Cheers,

Mike.